# QNAP TR-004 - How to mount this USB RAID 5 on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: mount

I've moved from Windoze to Linux and I have a QNAP TR-004, which is set up as RAID5 and accessible through USB-C on Windows without issue.  It was originally set up under Windows.

I would like to access the files using Ubuntu, but I can't figure out how to mount the drive.  I do believe it was most likely formatted as NTFS.  When I get access to a windows machine I will confirm.

Providing all the info I have.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I can see the unit when I plug it in (Device 13).

```
ndavie@Ubuntu21:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 27c6:609c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:5634 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Laptop Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 32ac:0002 Framework HDMI Expansion Card
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 1c04:0013 QNAP System Inc. TR-004
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

A new device shows up as /dev/sda

```
ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda
```

I don't see any partitions when using lsblk, but it is around 6TB of data

```
sudo lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
<snip>
sda           8:0    0   5.5T  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   931G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /
```

File isn't giving me any information (also tried sda0, sda1, sda2 [No such file)

```
sudo file -sL /dev/sda
/dev/sda: DOS/MBR boot sector MS-MBR Windows 7 english at offset 0x163 "Invalid partition table" at offset 0x17b "Error loading operating system" at offset 0x19a "Missing operating system"; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors
```

Digging through dmsg I see this as a last entry

```
[275771.742873] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[275771.768301] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1c04, idProduct=0013, bcdDevice=61.11
[275771.768305] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[275771.768306] usb 2-1: Product: TR-004
[275771.768307] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: QNAP Systems, Inc.
[275771.768307] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 51323036493039303338
[275771.769038] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[275771.769163] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[275772.783388] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     QNAP     TR-004 DISK00    6111 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[275772.783593] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[275772.783849] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[275772.783992] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 11720785920 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
[275772.783993] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[275772.784280] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[275772.784281] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 00 08
[275772.784691] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[275772.826971] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

and just for fun, I did try mounting using /dev/sda, sda1, sda2 - which doesn't work

```
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda /mnt/qnap
mount: /mnt/qnap: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda2 /mnt/qnap
mount: /mnt/qnap: special device /dev/sda2 does not exist.
```